# Load testing a multi-threaded system vs one using separate processes - why is the threaded version so much faster?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, process

I'm working on a system where three high level components interact

**Client(PHP)** -- **Logger (Java)** -- **MainBackend (Java)**

The PHP client creates a new Linux Logger process for each request received. Logger then sends a message over TCP to the MainBackend and begins logging messages it receives from MainBackend. Note that Logger is very lightweight and uses very little memory.

I load-tested this system, by increasing the number of users, N,  acessing the system.  I then wrote a version where Logger was multi-threaded so that only one process was used for each N simultaneous users and load-tested the threaded version.

The results were that the multi-threaded version was FAR faster, as in *many* times faster past a certain N.  My question is why?

If it takes a certain time T to start each Linux process, why amn't I seeing a constant difference (T2 - T1) between the two graphs?

Is Linux just far less efficient at scheduling processes than Java is at scheduling threads?

EDIT: An important point I didn't mention is that the timing was all done from within Logger, so the time to start the process / virtual machine is not affecting the results - I did the experiment this way so as to have as few variables as possible.

Comment: Yes, creating OS process is slower than creating Java thread.

Comment: You aren't accounting for the time it takes to start the Java virtual machine in this

Comment: I'm aware of this - but this should be a constant time too. I measured this as being about 145 milliseconds.  We're talking a LARGE difference here as in several seconds for reasonably large values of T.  The question is why T2 - T1 is not a constant, or at least reasonably constant.

Comment: I assume your client also waits for process shutdown? It could also take quiet some time.

Comment: and as a side note: keep a pool of thread workers, don't create way to many threads.

Answer (score 1):

JVM does runtime optimizations, especially for code executed repeatedly. This will take some time, a warm up period. The result can be insanely faster. You can time your task repeatedly in the same VM, you'll see that it's slow in the beginning but gets much faster in the end.

If you start a new JVM process for each small task, no optimization kicks in, before JVM is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Processes are more heavy weight than threads.  Using an existing process or existing TCP connection is much faster than creating a new one each time. This is true of all operating systems.  You would only create processes or connections on demand if performance wasn't an issue for you.

You will see some variation in the time it takes to do most tasks because the machine is trying to do several things at once.  You should always expect to see some variation.

Comment: The point is that a) we're talking the results of several tests here, b) the times I'm using are averaged, c) the threaded version gets increasingly efficient relative to the non-threaded version with increasing N - there is not a constant difference .  The variance you speak of should average out to a large degree as in the case of 80 users I'm averaging 80 numbers.  Although there _is_ noise on the graph, there is still a glaringly obvious trend.

Comment: As a JVM warms up it gets faster. It can get up to 10x faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is not only about time of creating a process or thread but about context switching too. You can find some numbers here: 
http://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch.

In short, structure with information about process is bigger than structure with data about thread.